# Can you grep/search case-insensitive in SchemaCrawler?

Tags: schemacrawler

Is there a flag or option that will allow SchemaCrawler to search database objects and ignore case?

The following example will filter out stored procedures that start with "API" even though they are desired output:

`--routines=.*api_Insert.*`

Answer (score 1):

Jared,

That is a good idea - I will add a `--ignore-case` option to the SchemaCrawler grep command. Meanwhile, you can try out a regular expression like

`--routines=.*[Aa][Pp][Ii]_Insert.*`

or

`--routines=.*(api|API)_Insert.*`

and see if that works.

Sualeh, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/).